# How can I find my SQLite database file on my computer?

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

I implemented my first app using Xamarin Studio (Mono for Android). This app stores some data in a SQLite db, which works fine on a Sony Tablet S device.

My question is: is there a way to get db file and see, for example, its size?

I looked up to the following path

```
/data/data/My-Application-Package-Name/databases/My-database-name
```

but it doesn't seem to exist.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: btw: it's "size" not "dimension"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Eclipse to go right to it using the sqlite manager plug-in (http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/)

- Download the *.jar file from the website I reference above to the
  "dropins" folder in eclipse (open your eclipse folder and you should
  see it)
- Then restart eclipse and go to the DDMS.  You may have to do
  windows->views-ddms if it isn't already being displayed...
- Select your device from the left panel then use the file explorer to go to your data
  directory/YOURAPP/databases.  Hopefully there will be an icon that
  shows up when you select your database. If not, rename your database to use the "db" ext.
- Click it and it should open in the manager tab.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Everything seems to work fine but when selecting my device's 'data' folder it seems to be empty! I can't figure out where MYAPP/databases files are...any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking for.  The "file size" may be different from the amount of data stored in it.  I haven't done it, but I know there are some pragma's that can tell you additional information.  Take a look at http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_page_count  You may also want to Google more responses using terms like "size" instead of "dimension".  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid database location (//data/data/My-Application-Package-Name/databases/My-database-name), but you can access it from file managers if you have root access only.
Look how it can be done [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1487020). Otherwise, if you want to get some info trough the code, you're doing something wrong, so publish the code and logcat.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I need just to know my db file size, since I read on sqlite documentation its max dimensions at run time can be approx 250KByte. Is that true?